# Configure FTP Server with two different IP addresses on different subnets and separate NICs

Tags: ubuntu, ip, ftp

I have an FTP server that's on a low bandwidth connection. We want to set it up with a second IP address on a much higher bandwidth connection. I set up the second interface with a static IP address on the faster connection. This unfortunately does not work. I can verify that the second IP address works perfectly when I disable the first IP address.

What do I need to do to get two separate interface IP addresses on different subnets working on the same server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running vsftpd standalone ? If you're running it from inetd, better switch to standalone.
Do you have listen_address in the vsftpd.conf ? If it's absent, vsftpd should listen on all interfaces available, when it's running standalone.

Comment: It's not currently in the conf file. I assume I can just add it in there?

Comment: Not really, without listen_address it should listen on all interfaces as you want. Did you restart vsftpd after adding second IP ?

Comment: restarted several times. I guess the real problem is that I couldn't ping both IP addresses when both were enabled. Only one would work at a time.